# How to get the rows non alphabetically in pivot table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=b0b8dc61e3e1a5be21fe201c2daadd0f)

Please Find the About fiddle link.

There i have table with the data.But when tried to pivot the table i am getting some rows in alphabetically order.
I don't want the rows to be converted to Alphabetical how can i restrict that Please help me .

I want to see the output like

```
A|B|C|January|February|December
-----------------------------
100|DEF|OL|200|290|100
100|ABC|OL|300|360|260
200|DEF|OL|600|550|500
200|ABC|OL|600|680|570
```

I dont want to change the order Please help me.

I have searched but nothing worked for me.If i use order by case coulmn-name when '' then 1
gives me syntax error

Comment: I can't get it. You want to swap the values for `DEF` and `ABC` but this is how their values are inserted. The `PIVOT` is doing exactly what it is suppose to do and there is nothing incorrect with it.

Comment: You can see In B column of result table the row values are displayed in Alphabetically.But the data is coming out correctly but the problem is i dont want to change the order I have table with the order Frist DEF and then ABC but after pivoting it is displaying ABC and then DEF

Comment: it seems that A 100, DEF has two records in December (E100 and E260) so using the max will give you E260, while you need the E100 of that record . So, you need to deal with B records that has duplicates E, and also, there is no E260 for A 100, B ABC in December. So, make sure of source data, then you'll get the expected output.

Comment: @roll Why just you do not `order by A ASC, B DESC`?

Comment: @gotqn i have lot of data , so i can't sort based on order by asc or desc the values are  not in alphabetic : i have three values DFF,ABC and STU

Comment: @roll you need to define a rule for how data is sorted. It is not clear how you want to sort the data, but only how not to sort it. Do you have such requirements?

Comment: The **only** thing that gives you any control over the final order of rows output from a query is an explicit `ORDER BY` clause on the outermost query. If you fail to specify one, you get the rows in whatever order are most convenient for the server to deliver them in.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever can you explain how can use Order by case coulmn_name
when 'DEF' then 1
when 'ABC' then 2
End
is this is possible?

Comment: Use this example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49426139/sorting-month-name-in-dynamic-pivot

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  So your original data has no ordering.  You can assign an ordering by providing an `id` column.  Then you can do the following:

- Calculate the minimum id for combinations of `a`/`b`/`c`.
- Order by this minimum id

You can see this solution in this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=900121ca6328834516476734692060bb).

The change in the pivot code is:

```
set @sql = '
select A,B,C,'+@col_list+' 
from (select  a, b, c, d, e, min(id) over (partition by a, b, c) as min_id
      from t1
     ) t1
pivot (max([E]) for [D] in ('+@col_list+'))pv
order by min_id'
```